# How to install sklearn?

Tags: python

I have a program for digit recognition and I already installed the NumPy and OpenCv libraries. However, I also need to install the sklearn library. Please help me figure out how to install it on my system.

Comment: presumably the same way as you installed the others

Comment: Which operating system? and for which Python version?

Comment: for windows type pip install -U scikit-learn in cmd. insde this directory C:\Python27\Scripts

Answer (score 48):

```
pip install numpy scipy scikit-learn
```

if you don't have pip, install it using

```
python get-pip.py
```

Download get-pip.py from the [following link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#do-i-need-to-install-pip).
or use curl to download it.

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Comment: I received below error when I try above commands-ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'scipy,', 'at', ',')

Comment: probably you are using old version of pip
`pip -V`
if it is older than 9, please upgrade your pip
`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 16):

You didn't provide us which operating system are you on?
If it is a Linux, make sure you have scipy installed as well, after that just do

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

If you are on windows you might want to check out [these pages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn).

- [Source](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#install-by-distribution)

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend you look at getting the anaconda package, it will install and configure Sklearn and its dependencies.

https://www.continuum.io

Comment: @angit [Here](https://eatsleepdata.com/blogs/machine-learning/how-to-install-python-machine-learning-packages-using-anaconda) is an example of using Anaconda to install Scikit-learn (Sklearn).

Comment: I use the anaconda-navigator. You just click on the package in the gui and it will install itself.